# A Rank-One Reduction Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $A_{m\times n}$ is very large, dense and full rank matrix. How can I find matrix B such that $\operatorname{rank}(B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)-1$? (Rank reduction formula must be invertible and can go back to the original matrix.)

I find Wedderburn Rank Reduction but Inversion impossible here because $A^{-1}$ is large and I can't store it.

Comment: Does "no constraints are imposed" mean that the matrix $B$ can (except the rank condition) be arbitrary?

Comment: No, means that preserve original matrix properties such as symmetry and positive definiteness, orthogonality and etc.

Comment: So you want $m=n$? All of those properties require that (and in fact, you'd need that to even consider $A^{-1}$ in the first place). I think you need to be more specific about what properties you're trying to preserve since the answer may be different in each case. Also, I'm pretty sure you're not going to be able to find an "invertible" such formula since if you did have one and applied it again to $B$, and again to the result, etc., you'll always eventually get the zero matrix, regardless of the starting matrix $A$.

Comment: Well even if you wanted it to preserve the properties, there still a lot of freedom how to chose $B$. Any rank-one update can be of course "inverted" by switching the sign of the update. However, this inversion cannot be deduced from the reduced matrix.